# Send and receive POST request in Playframework

Tags: java, playframework

I am writing application on playframework. I have a search form and I want to send POST request and be able to accept it in my controller, how this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There Many samples for it, First Add a method login in your Application (or whatever) controller.

Lets assume your posting login details for your controller.

```
public static void  login(String userCode,String password){        
    User loginUser = User.find("byUserCodeAndPassword",userCode,password).first();
    if(loginUser == null){
        flash.put("username",userCode);
        flash.error("Invalid Credentials");
        index();
    }
    else{
        Cache.set(session.getId(),loginUser,"20mn");
        Home.Home();
    }
}
```

In your conf/routes file add

```
    POST    /                                       Application.login
```

Assuming you have a index.html in your app/views/Application folder.

From the Html Page:

```
<div id="login">
#{form @login(), id:'formLogin'}
<p class="field">
    <label>User Code:</label>
    <input type="text"  name="userCode" size="19" value="${flash.userCode}" required>
 </p>

<p class="field">
    <label>Password:</label>
    &nbsp;<input type="password" name="password" size="19" required>
</p>
<p class="buttons">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</p>
#{/form}
```

Comment: What if I post search form with multiple parameters? Some of them might be inserted, some of them not and I need to accept Map<String,String> into controller.